# how to fix 'method' object is not subscriptablein pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my problem is that when I want to delete the number 1 from the beginning of the cell from a certain column, it gives this error, what should I do to fix it?

my code:

```
S_T_1 = r"C:\Users\a.heidarzadeh\OneDrive\دسکتاپ\charisma project\excel file creat\S T+1.xlsx"
S_T_2 = r"C:\Users\a.heidarzadeh\OneDrive\دسکتاپ\charisma project\excel file creat\S T+2.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(S_T_1)
df['Unnamed: 5'] = df['Unnamed: 5'].str.replace["1"," "]
df
```

The column I want to modify:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHYPB.jpg)
my error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\a.heidarzadeh\OneDrive\دسکتاپ\charisma project\excel file creat\MAIN.ipynb Cell 5 in ()
      2 S_T_2 = r"C:\Users\a.heidarzadeh\OneDrive\دسکتاپ\charisma project\excel file creat\S T+2.xlsx"
      3 df = pd.read_excel(S_T_1)
----> 4 df['Unnamed: 5'] = df['Unnamed: 5'].str.replace["1"," "]
      5 df

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Actually, I didn't think of anything special to do

Comment: Line 4 should be `df['Unnamed: 5'] = df['Unnamed: 5'].str.replace("1"," ")`. Use parentheses `()` when calling functions or methods, not brackets `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

@MattDmo answered in comments:

Line 4 should be `df['Unnamed: 5'] = df['Unnamed: 5'].str.replace("1"," ")`.

Use parentheses () when calling functions or methods, not brackets [].